# Problem in higher order components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning how to use higher order components. There I want to highlight some text. In my code I can highlight the whole line by using `<div>`. The problem is I only want to highlight a part of the text. So I tried `<span>`. But when I use span the whole highlighting part doesn't work. Since it doesn't give any error I can't understand what where the error comes from.

**HighlightedText.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UpdatedComponent from './Hoc';

class HighlightedText extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Highlighted Text</h1>
    }
}



export default UpdatedComponent(HighlightedText);
```

**Hoc.js**

```
const UpdatedComponent = OriginalComponent => {
    class NewComponent extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return(props) =>(
                <div style={{ background: 'Yellow', padding: 2 }}>

                    <OriginalComponent {...props}/>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    return NewComponent;
}

export default UpdatedComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. Your HOC looks to be trying to return a functional component from the render method of a class-based component.
2. Props aren't spread correctly.
3. `padding: 2` may not be valid, it should probably provide a unit, whatever you need

## Solution

To fix the highlighting I believe you just need to specify a `display: inline-block;` CSS rule to the div. Spread `this.props` from the class-based component to the wrapped component.

```
const updatedComponent = (OriginalComponent) => {
  class NewComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            background: "Yellow",
            padding: "1rem", // <-- provide unit, 1rem ~ 16px
            display: "inline-block" // <-- inline-block display
          }}
        >
          <OriginalComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return NewComponent;
};
```

[image]

[image: Edit problem-in-higher-order-components-in-react]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight just a part of the text, it requires modifying the virtual DOM tree returned by the original component, since you can't just easily wrap it like in your example. You might want to use [react-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace) to achieve this.